# How to move files older than 'x' day along with folder structure in cent OS

Tags: linux, centos6, mv

I have a requirement where I need to move files older than 7 days to my SAN. But I want to run move command from a parent directory so that the files in subfolders are moved to SAN along with their folder structure intact.
OS - Cent Os 6.9

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Here is the command I used. I tried rsync but below command moves all the files, even the files which are less than 7 days old.    **find /home/nkumar/Test -type f -mtime +7 -exec rsync -av "/home/nkumar/Test/" /home/nkumar/chkmv --remove-source-files \; **

Comment: that `rsync` command is synchronizing the entire contents of the Test directory, there is nothing passing the names found from the `find` command to `rsync`. Using `mv` instead of `rsync` in the `-exec` argument may work. Use `{}` to refer to the found file name in `-exec`.

Comment: mv does not move the subfolders, it just moves files from the subfolders. But my requirement is to move the files along with their folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working. Here is the command I am now using to move the files with sub folders intact and then deleting the files from source directory.

```
find /home/nkumar/eur/ -type f -mtime +7 -printf %P\\0 | rsync --files-from=- --from0 /home/nkumar/eur/ /home/nkumar/chk/ --remove-sent-files
```

Comment: Great! I was looking for this kind of subtree move for quite a while. I don't understand what the printf is needed for.